# How to return model with virtual property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a model like this,

```
[Table("ClientAccessories")]
public class ClientAccessory
{
    public ClientAccessory()
    {
        LastModifiedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public string AccessoryId { get; set; }

    public Guid ClientReference { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Accessory Accessory { get; set; }
}
```

and I have this code in repository method,

```
    public IEnumerable<ClientAccessory> GetClientAccessories(Guid ClientReference)
    {
        var _context = new DBContext();

      var results = from a in _context.Accessories
                         join ca in _context.ClientAccessories
                               on new { AccessoryId = a.Id, ClientReference = new Guid(ClientReference) }
                           equals new { ca.AccessoryId, ca.ClientReference } into ca_join
                         from ca in ca_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where
                           ca.IsActive == true ||
                           ca.IsActive == null
                           select new {};
    }
```

Now problem is that, I am not sure how to return ClientAccessory including Accessory object together even though it's a virtual property.

Also Is it Okay to call 2 entities in one repository or should I return IQueryable and do it in domain service class. thank you.

I don't want to flat the values like this,

```
 select new {
 Id = a.Id,
 ClientReference = ca.ClientReference
 and so on...

};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you query from ClientAccessory and include the Accessory, you should get what you what. Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ClientAccessory> GetClientAccessories(Guid ClientReference)
{
    var _context = new DBContext();

    var results = from ca in _context.ClientAccessory.Include("Accessory")
        where ca.IsActive == true || ca.IsActive == null
        select ca;
    return results;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks but this doesn't work, it doesn't returns results from Accessory which doesn't exists in ClientAccessory table